# Regex to match these number rules

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I'm currently using

```
str.matches("\\d")
```

but its only matching a single number.

I need to match ints and doubles, e.g. :

```
"1"
"1337"
".1"
"13.7"
```

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Is this part of some particular programming language you might wish to tell us about?

Comment: Java - sorry about that.

Comment: would you also want negative numbers ("-1.734")?  How about exponential ("12.34e-56")?  Also, are you looking to match the entire string?  @gintas gave a great basic answer, but it assumes that input is bounded at the beginning and end of search input, by the '^' and '$', which is great if you want that, but not great if you don't.

Comment: The numbers will always be positive and I don't want exponential numbers. Is @gintas answer the way to go?

Comment: That or @gnomed, depending on whether you want to constrain to match the full string exactly or not (i.e., the '^' and '$')

Comment: I don't see the need to catch groups with parenthesis in @gintas solution...

Comment: I'm liking @Franco's mod better now.  I don't know why gintas had the outer capture, but the inner capture is actually to group the quantifier, I think.

Comment: I saw that after, by the way, doing `(\\d+)?` is the exactly same thing than doing `\\d*` and there is no need to group the dot. I stay on my position :)

Comment: sure 'nuf. I think yours is the most succinct, without "over-engineering" for inputs not needed by the poster

Comment: What about numbers like 0000009?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is tidier to look at than the other suggestions, while still doing the same thing.

`(\\d+)?(\\.)?\\d+`

Comment: as mentioned in earlier answer comments, you need single backslash in this case instead of double.  But I'll let you edit instead of downvoting ;-)

Comment: OP listed Java as the language. Whats wrong with providing a string he does not have to modify?

Comment: OK, I'll grant that.  My bad.

Comment: That fails on `35.` you know.

Comment: true, but that isn't in his sample inputs.  I guess we need to clarify requirements

Answer (score 5):

You can try this regexp:

```
 ^(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$
```

Comment: Only double backslash instead of single one.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov No, one uses single backslashes in regexes. What he wrote is correct, as far as it goes. You’re thinking of how to sneak it past the Java compiler to make up for Java’s ignorance of regexes as proper 1ˢᵗ-class citizens.

Answer (score 5):

I think this regular expression can help you

```
\\d*\\.?\\d+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
((\+|-)?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+))
```

This would match positive and negative ints, doubles that start with a digit, and doubles start with a dot

Answer (score 1):

This will match any real number that the Java compiler will recognize.  To do this, it also handles things like signed numbers and exponentials.  It’s in `Pattern.COMMENTS` mode because I think anything else is barbaric.

```
(?xi)                      # the /i is for the exponent
(?:[+-]?)                  # the sign is optional
(?:(?=[.]?[0123456789])
   (?:[0123456789]*)
   (?:(?:[.])
      (?:[0123456789]{0,})
   ) ?
)
# this is where the exponent starts, if you want it
(?:(?:[E])
   (?:(?:[+-]?)
      (?:[0123456789]+)
   ) 
   |
)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a quite extensive [lesson about regular expressions in the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).

For information about matching multiple characters you should read the section about [quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).